# Calling name error in agecheck method

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.util.*;

public class newclass {
public static String name;     

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){

    newclass picname = new newclass();
    picname.namechecker();
    picname.agechecker();

}
public void namechecker(){
System.out.println("Please enter your name new user");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello " + name + "!");

}
public void agechecker(){
System.out.println("What is your age " + name); 
int age = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("You're " + age + " years old");
}

}
```

For some reason whenever I enter my name. Java would not recall it in the agechecker() method. I do not know why it wouldn't since I used it as a global variable. Can someone please explain this to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short answer: hiding. You're declaring a local `name` that hides the `name` in your class. Skip the type declarations in your methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

you input name in `namechecker()` and assign it to

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

and you are expecting it to be set in static field called name as well

```
System.out.println("What is your age " + name);
```

so it would be `null`

**solution:**

dirty: assign name to global variable as well
better: create a class called `Person` and have its `Object`